# Using a database connection string stored in environment variable during migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-string, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have ASP.NET Core project in which I store my PostgreSQL connection string in an environment variable. When I try to do the initial migration the project's build succeeds, but then it throws an exception:

*System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').*

So I assume that it does not read the connection string correctly.
I provide connection string to my DbContext in ConfigureServices method like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<GoalsContext>(options =>  
  options.UseNpgsql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_STRING")));
```

I also have tried to fix this by creating an implementation of IDesignTimeDbContextFactory like this:

```cs
public class GoalsContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<GoalsContext>
{
  public GoalsContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
  {
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GoalsContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_STRING");

    return new GoalsContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
  }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

**Update:**
I have as suggested in the comments read the official documentation on Environment variables and configuration and I have checked whether the variable exists in the first place by creating a controller with one method, which returns a connection string like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public string GetConnectionString()
{
  return _config["CONNECTION_STRING"];
}
```

And correct connection string indeed shows up in the browser when I launch it, but when I tried to add initial migration to database the exception that I have already mentioned is still thrown.

I have also tried to comment out my implementation of IDesignTimeDbContextFactory and to manually add a call to .AddEnvironmentVariables method in my Program.cs (which I read is done automatically, but I still wanted to try), but none of that had any effect - my controller still puts out connection string while Entity Framework Core's migration still does not receive it.

So in short, yes connection string exists and I can even output it, but migration still fails due to the same exception.

Comment: Does the environment variable exist in the first place? Don't use one-liners, store the env variable value in a temporary variable and debug your code. The exception suggests it's null, which means it's simply not set when running this code

Comment: BTW this has nothing to do with EF or EF migrations. Not even ASP.NET Core, as you call `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` directly. This means there's no `CONNECTION_STRING` environment variable.

Comment: The *correct* way would be to use environment variables in .NET Core in general is to use the [Environment variable configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables-configuration-provider), which allows you to decouple services like EF from the configuration source, and provide the settings through files, databases, the cli or environment variables

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I will read more on an article you linked and will try to implement those things and debug a little more. I will post an update after I will finish.

Comment: My main point is that there's no such environment variable right now. Have you set it? How did you test the code?

Comment: Did you restart your Visual Studio or IIS? Environment variable change doesn't take an effect until you restart the application.

Comment: Yes I did restart server and Visual Studio many times while debugging, problem is not there.

Comment: [Does This Help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288247/asp-net-core-2-1-unable-to-run-migrations-due-to-environment-variable?rq=1) If you are running your migrations from a Visual Studio "Package Manager Window" or other shell, you might find you need to set the variable before `Add-Migration` or `Update-Database` is called. Terminal Windows don't tend to inherit the Environment Variables of your user account, or whatever visual studio is running as.

Comment: This indeed did help. Manually setting environment variable in Package manager console solved this issue. Thank you for your input. One last question I have, is there a way to not have to manually set environment variable before every migration? I tried to change my lauchSettings.json file's properties to copy it to output, but that didn't work.

Comment: By the way, you can write an answer and I will accept it, because your comment correctly answers the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment.

See [Command Line Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288247/asp-net-core-2-1-unable-to-run-migrations-due-to-environment-variable?rq=1)

Also, if you want to bypass the setting of the variables, you'll need to look into the `OnConfiguring` Method overload of the Context and use the `IsConfigured` flag on the DbOptions parameter passed in to only read from a file when no valid config is passed to the context.

I should caveat that to say, that this also leads to issues when other developers use the solution and also, you shouldn't check the files you read into a public source control repository as this is one way people get credentials for things they shouldn't, look into [User Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows)